# Download links with TideSDK

Tags: download, hyperlink, tidesdk

I have seen several posts coming close to solving my issue, but I am still not able to accomplish my simple task, which is this:

Imagine I have a window which contains a link to a remote file (most often it will be a zip file). How can I structure and call a function that accesses the file and opens a "Save As" dialogue so that the user can choose where to save the downloaded file? It would be nice to be able to pass different variables from other links to the same function to accomplish the same thing for other downloadable files.

And yes, I am completely new to TideSDK and not exactly a javascript expert, if this is causing much painful slapping of foreheads.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

Any link with a class of "save-as" will trigger the "Save as" dialog. The file will be saved AFTER the user selects the location, gives it a name and clicks Save. This does use jquery.

```
<a href="http://wordpress.org/latest.zip" class="save-as">Download WordPress</a>    

    <script>

        $(function(){
            var currentLink;
            $('.save-as').click(function() { 
                var link = $(this).attr('href');
                var filename = link.substring(link.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
                currentLink = link;
                Ti.UI.currentWindow.openSaveAsDialog(saveComplete, {
                    title: 'Save As...',
                    multiple: false,
                    defaultName : filename
                });
                return false;
            }); // End save as.

            var saveComplete = function(results) {
                if(results.length>0) {
                    var downloadFile = results[0];
                    console.log("Download the file");
                    var httpClient = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient();
                    httpClient.open('GET', currentLink);
                    httpClient.receive(function(data) {
                      var file = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(downloadFile);
                      var fileStream = file.open(Ti.Filesystem.MODE_APPEND);
                      fileStream.write(data);
                      fileStream.close();
                    });
                }
            };

        });



    </script>
```